# print([[i+j for i in "abc"] for j in "def"])

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm new to Python.

I stumped upon with one of this comprehension

```
print([[i+j for i in "abc"] for j in "def"])
```

Could you please help me convert the comprehension in for loop?

I'm not getting the desired result by for loop:

```
list = []
list2 = []

for j in 'def':
    for i in 'abc':
        list.append(i+j)
    list2 = list
print (list)
```

the above is my try with for loop. I' missing something. Below should be the desired result in for loop that i want.

`([[‘ad’, ‘bd’, ‘cd’], [‘ae’, ‘be’, ‘ce’], [‘af’, ‘bf’, ‘cf’]])`

which I believe is a matrice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code and I got your result. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Recommended read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-in-python-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-us

Comment: there are 2 for loops in this code! the result is `[['ad', 'bd', 'cd'], ['ae', 'be', 'ce'], ['af', 'bf', 'cf']]`. what is your expected result?

Comment: what is the expected result??

Comment: If you are getting an *unexpected* result, that implies you have a for loop that you are using to get it. Please share your loop here.

Comment: i want to use the above comprehension in terms of for loop. hre is what i tried with list = []
list2 = []

for j in 'def':
    for i in 'abc':
        list.append([i+j])
    list2 = list
print (list)

Comment: Code seems fine. It's not a matrix though, it's a list of lists.

Comment: @Sunil Please [edit] the post. Don't add code in comments.

Comment: `.append(i+j)` not `.append([i+j])`

Comment: Do not use `list` as a name for a variable. It silently trashes the function `list()` of the same name.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to unravel a comprehension like this is to take it one comprehension at a time and write *that* as a loop.  So:

```
[[i+j for i in "abc"] for j in "def"]
```

becomes:

```
outer_list = []
for j in "def":
    outer_list.append([i + j for i in "abc"])
```

Alright, cool.  Now we've gotten rid of the outer comprehension so we can unravel the inner comprehension next:

```
outer_list = []
for j in "def":
    inner_list = []
    for i in "abc":
        inner_list.append(i + j)
    outer_list.append(inner_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop for this comprehension will look like this

```
result = []
for j in "def":
    r = []
    for i in "abc":
        r.append(i+j)
    result.append(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'abc'
b = 'def'

>>> [[x+y for x in a]for y in b]
[['ad', 'bd', 'cd'], ['ae', 'be', 'ce'], ['af', 'bf', 'cf']]
```

### Loop

```
>>> for y in b:
...     for x in a:
...         print x+y,
... 
ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf
```